# get/show Last ID

Tags: plugins, php, mysql, forms, plugin-contact-form-7

When our users submit a form (Contact 7), I want to get the next available **Auto-Increment** number (*order-post-ID*) and insert this into one of the fields. This is sent along with the form in order to create a link to the Flamingo Inbound Message post.

As of now, it works but is not entirely accurate. Every so often, the number sent is one lower than the actual post ID. For example, one order can be accessed through the dashboard:

> /wp-admin/admin.php?page=flamingo_inbound&post=8601

However, the *order-post-ID* sent with this was 8600. I've tried disabling the buttons and auto-saving to ensure that multiple submissions are not occurring; am I missing something obvious?

My code is below:

```
function getLastID() {

    global $wpdb;

    $next = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
            "
            SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
            FROM information_schema.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'wordpressDB'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'wp_posts'
            "
            ), 0, 0 );

    echo $next;

    $wpdb->flush();

    exit();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is in the `wp_posts` table for ID = 8600 ?

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't even thought to look at the posts which were being lost in the ether - looks like my ajax call is returning data and submitting the post before another function has finished running. Dropped a callback into the code - marking your answer as correct since I believe you've helped to solve this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to have the ID, you can try this hook e.g.

```
add_action("save_post", function ($post_ID, $post, $update) {


    if (    !$update
        &&  class_exists("Flamingo_Inbound_Message")
        &&  (Flamingo_Inbound_Message::post_type === $post->post_type)
    ) {

        // here $post_ID is the ID of the new created inbound message


    }


}, 10, 3);
```